# Crypto Exception in Elixir

Tags: cryptography, elixir, plug

I have configured an elixir app and defined admin routes. But, I am getting the following error while trying to access any routes.

> (exit) an exception was raised:
>       ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>           (crypto) :crypto.hmac_nif(:sha256, {:system, "Zpumk6KLEY8Qx826qspHhYrpTpDswFzHL/64aJWqhPyYZQWbV3hWq+nUIPQRMwLn"},
>   <<48, 70, 98, 86, 85, 68, 57, 56, 0, 0, 0, 1>>)
>           (crypto) crypto.erl:925: :crypto.hmac/6
>           (plug) lib/plug/crypto/key_generator.ex:64: Plug.Crypto.KeyGenerator.generate/7
>           (plug) lib/plug/crypto/key_generator.ex:50: Plug.Crypto.KeyGenerator.with_cache/3
>           (plug) lib/plug/session/cookie.ex:88: Plug.Session.COOKIE.get/3
>           (plug) lib/plug/session.ex:75: anonymous fn/5 in Plug.Session.fetch_session/1
>           (plug) lib/plug/debugger.ex:195: Plug.Debugger.maybe_fetch_session/1
>           (plug) lib/plug/debugger.ex:150: Plug.Debugger.render/6
>           (plug) lib/plug/debugger.ex:129: Plug.Debugger.**catch**/5
>           (my_app) lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex:1: MyAppWeb.Endpoint.call/2
>           (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4

Here is the content of lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex.

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app

  socket "/socket", MyAppWeb.UserSocket

  # Serve at "/" the static files from "priv/static" directory.
  #
  # You should set gzip to true if you are running phoenix.digest
  # when deploying your static files in production.
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :my_app, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)

  # Code reloading can be explicitly enabled under the
  # :code_reloader configuration of your endpoint.
  if code_reloading? do
    socket "/phoenix/live_reload/socket", Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket
    plug Phoenix.LiveReloader
    plug Phoenix.CodeReloader
  end

  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug Plug.Logger

  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json, Absinthe.Plug.Parser],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison

  plug Plug.MethodOverride
  plug Plug.Head

  # The session will be stored in the cookie and signed,
  # this means its contents can be read but not tampered with.
  # Set :encryption_salt if you would also like to encrypt it.
  plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_my_app_key",
    signing_salt: "0FbVUD98"

  plug MyAppWeb.Router

  @doc """
  Callback invoked for dynamically configuring the endpoint.

  It receives the endpoint configuration and checks if
  configuration should be loaded from the system environment.
  """
  def init(_key, config) do
    if config[:load_from_system_env] do
      port = System.get_env("PORT") || raise "expected the PORT environment variable to be set"
      {:ok, Keyword.put(config, :http, [:inet6, port: port])}
    else
      {:ok, config}
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone, please help?

Comment: Please give your `lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex` 's content.

Comment: @YongHaoHu Added the endpoint.ex file content.

Comment: Did you  set the :secret_key_base field in your connection? See: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Session.COOKIE.html

Comment: @YongHaoHu I tried adding the put_secret_key_base in my endpoint.ex. But, didn't work. For some reason, _my_app_key is not getting generated and stored in Cookies. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did u try using `:log ` to debug it ?

Comment: Thanks @YongHaoHu. put_secret_key_base worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(exit) an exception was raised:
** (ArgumentError) argument error (crypto) :crypto.hmac_nif(:sha256, {:system, "Zpumk6KLEY8Qx826qspHhYrpTpDswFzHL/64aJWqhPyYZQWbV3hWq+nUIPQRMwLn"}, <<48, 70, 98, 86, 85, 68, 57, 56, 0, 0, 0, 1>>)
(crypto) crypto.erl:925: :crypto.hmac/6 
(plug) lib/plug/crypto/key_generator.ex:64: Plug.Crypto.KeyGenerator.generate/7 
(plug) lib/plug/crypto/key_generator.ex:50: Plug.Crypto.KeyGenerator.with_cache/3 
(plug) lib/plug/session/cookie.ex:88: Plug.Session.COOKIE.get/3 
lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4`

Your error log is related to [`Plug.Session.COOKIE`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Session.COOKIE.html).

As the doc said,

> Since this store uses crypto features, it requires you to set the :secret_key_base field in your connection. This can be easily achieved with a plug:

It seems that you didn't do this part in your code.